# Adding a image to the JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

I'm currently trying to add a hangman image to my `JPanel`. I have labeled image 1-10 and increment the value each time the user gets a wrong answer (this is working). As of yet I haven't been able to get the image to work. How to I properly insert my image?

```
if(!found){
  numError++;

  String userError = Integer.toString(numError);
  String jpg = userError.concat(".JPG");
  try{
    BufferedImage myImg = ImageIO.read(new File(jpg));
    JLabel hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myImg));
    hangman.setSize(200,100);
    hangman.setLocation(300, 20);
    add(hangman);
  }catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
at HangmanPanel$1.actionPerformed(HangmanPanel.java:73)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
...
```

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: Please see [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson oops I missed that

Comment: So this isn't about the way i coded it???

Comment: I mean other then printStackTrace()

Comment: *"I mean other then printStackTrace()"*  Put the line in there and **give us the stack trace!**  Otherwise I'm voting to close as 'not a real question'. I'm sick of trying to make random guesses based in pitiful levels of information.  :-/

Comment: You never asked for the error's "Change code of the form catch (Exception e) { .. to catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative!"
Which i did in my own code and have been trying to figure out the answer

Comment: point second, most important, never to create/set/modify/delete/remove Swing GUI element inside, try - catch - finally block

Comment: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at HangmanPanel$1.actionPerformed(HangmanPanel.java:70)

Comment: @mKorbel: eclipse wont let me set BufferedImage myImg = ImageIO.read(new File(jpg)); outside a try/catch and if i move the four lines after that they will be out of scope.

Comment: Edit the exception stack trace into the question & use code formatting on it.  Also show the altered code while you are at it.

Comment: :-)... :-), good one, 1. hasn't something with eclipse, 2. myImg should be local variable, 3. added intialized and not null ImageIcon to JLabel, 4. have to test, because Icon/ImageIcon can be null 5. never caused an exception, where is Icon/ImageIcon with null value added to JComponent (JLabel in your case)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "into the question". The parameter for the catch block?

Comment: *"The parameter for the catch block?"*  Yes, as well as the exception output - I can't read exceptions in comments!  Or more accurately, I have no intention of trying..

Comment: I bet that this is a path problem when he is trying to read the file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i updated the code to what is currently on my screen with the output from the catch block

Comment: She and not that I'm aware of that is the first thing i looked for i have the .jpg files place in the main dir of both the src and the bin folder... I wasn't sure if it needed to be with the .java or .class. Wouldn't the path just be the file name it self, if its stored in the same folder as the .java/.class file?

Comment: OK now, we might be getting closer to a solution.. I'm guessing this image is effectively 'part of the game' right?  In that case it should be (& probably is at the moment - if using an IDE) an [tag:embedded-resource], something inside one of the Jar files.  Answer that question and I should be able to offer an actual answer..

Comment: yes it is "part of the game". I'm sorry I'm rather new to all this... the img's do show up in the Package Explorer in the default package which everything is in... I believe i remember reading about Jar file's-- isn't that something you create later? again I'm sorry this is all very new to me.

Comment: *"isn't that something you create later?"*  (shrugs) Depends on the environment, in any case, I'll have an answer in a few moments with more info.

Answer (score 2):

Since image this will become an application resource that is embedded in a Jar file, the image *must be accessed by URL.*  See the [embedded resource info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the overview of how to form that URL.  The only tricky thing left is to determine exactly what `String` to use.

> I have the .jpg files place in the main dir of both the src and the bin folder.

OK, if the image is called `hungman.JPG` the `String` to find it would be `"/hungman.JPG"`

### Especially note

1. The leading `/` which tells the class-loader to search from 'the root of the class-path'.
2. The case of the name must be exactly right.  This does not matter with Windows and `File` instances, but it always does with URLs.

**Note:**  accessing the image by URL will work *either* in a Jar *or* as long as the image is on the run-time class-path of the application.  So even if the IDE does not automatically Jar the classes and resources, it should still work.

Comment: I'm still getting the error Can't read input file! but thanks all the same this was still very helpful

Comment: It's time to check things more closely.  Do you use an IDE?  If so, which one?  What is the run-time class-path?  Is it putting the resources into Jars to run, or simply using the class files..?

Comment: eclipse. /1.jpg. and I'm not sure how i would create a Jar file so class file i think

Comment: OK, look in the directory Eclipse stores the class files (`bin/`?), see if you can find `1.jpg` in there.

Comment: would this cause an issue 
'numError++;
String userError = Integer.toString(numError);
String newUserError = userError.concat(".jpg");'

Comment: If `1.jpg` is in `bin/1.jpg` I am stumped as to why it is not being found.

Answer (score 1):

try directly creating the imageIcon using url of jpg.then
    JLabel hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(urlOfImageFile));

Comment: JLabel hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myImg)); this has been in the code since the beginning